# Riemann Integrability via Riemann sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I  know that if a bounded function is integrable on a compact interval $[a,b]$ and if $ lim_{||P||\to 0}
\sum_{i=0}^n f(t_i) \Delta x_i $ exists

where $||p|| $ is the mesh of a partition $P$ of $[a,b] P=${$x_0=a, x_1, x_2....x_n$}$ n \in N $ and $t_i$ is an arbitrary point in the interval $\Delta x_i=[x_{(i-1)},x_i]$, the definite integral is equal to the limit of the sum say $I$.

But does the converse hold, if the limit holds for any particular choice points $t_i \in \Delta x_i $ does it imply the function is integrable, or should it be proved that for any arbitary point $t_i$ the limit holds and if so is it sufficient to deduce that the function is integrable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;x\in \Bbb Q\cap [0,1]\\{}\\0&,\;\;x\in [0,1]\setminus\left(\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]\right)\end{cases}$$

isn't Riemann integral in $\;[1,0]\;$ , yet if you get to choose the points in each subinterval of each partition then the corresponding Riemann sums converge.

The definition for Riemann integrability *requires* the points in each subinterval of each partition **must** be artbitrary.

What you *can* do is: if you already know the function is R. integrable, then you can freely choose the points in the subintervals.

Comment: To elaborate, for this $f$ and *any* partition $P$, you can pick your $t_i$ to either be all rational, in which case the sum is $1$, or all irrational, in which case the sum is $0$. The thus depends on the particular choice of the $t_i$, and the function is therefore not riemann integrable.